# How do I stop python json.dump from converting integer 0 to a string?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

In python I have an EasyDict object that houses a list of config params similar to that shown below. When I call json.dump, it writes out everything as expected, except it converts the final entry shown, GPU_ID to a string literal "0" rather than the int zero I expect.  Before reading in my outputed config json file I have to remove the quotation marks from around the 0 and then everything works as expected. I would prefer not to have to manually adjust this every time.  I looked through the documentation, but have yet to find anything that works.  Is there a way around this?

```
from easydict import EasyDict as ed
myConfig = ed()

myConfig.MOMENTUM = 0.9
myConfig.WEIGHT_DECAY = 0.0001
myConfig.BATCH_SIZE=256
myConfig.GPU_ID = 0
```

Calling this:

```
with open(os.path.join(folder_to_dump, file_path), "w") as f:
        json.dump(myConfig, f, indent=4)
```

Outputs the below:

```
{
  "MOMENTUM" : 0.9,
  "WEIGHT_DECAY" : 0.0001,
  "BATCH_SIZE" : 256,
  "GPU_ID" : "0"
}
```

However what I am wanting is this:

```
{
  "MOMENTUM" : 0.9,
  "WEIGHT_DECAY" : 0.0001,
  "BATCH_SIZE" : 256,
  "GPU_ID" : 0
}
```

Comment: is it `json` or the `easydict` that does the conversion to `str`?

Comment: I just tested and `json` works. your easydict stuff is probably at fault. But why did it react differently on "256" ??

Comment: Just tested your complete code with easydict, and I can't reproduce the problem, I get an integer `0` in the output file.

Comment: `json.dumps(myConfig, indent=4)` works for me, outputting `0` as `int`

Comment: Thank you both for the help. The fact that you weren't able to reproduce, sent me back to look a little deeper and as you stated Jean-François Fabre, the issue was with easydict.  I still don't get why it handled one int different than another, but I updated to the latest version and retried and it is now working as expected.  Strange issue, but if you submit it as an answer I will accept it.  Thank you both again!

Comment: This raises the question: do you trust `EasyDict` enough to continue using it, instead of using a vanilla namespace class like `class Namespace: pass`? Then `myConfig = Namespace()`, set the attributes the same, and finally `json.dump(myConfig.__dict__, f, indent=4)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jean-François stated above, the answer was to update easydict to the latest. I unfortunately am unsure as to why 0 was being treated differently than other integers, however this seemed to resolve my problem